# Swift repeated gradient color

Tags: ios, swift, gradient

I am trying to get the exact text color used in a powerpoint over to my swift ios app.  I have been able to get a single gradient shift from one color to another, but am unable to figure out how to make a gradient shift back and forth like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This article covers multiple gradient colors and much more.
https://www.appcoda.com/cagradientlayer/

If you are using CAGradientLayer as in the article, the relevant idea would be to add more CGColors to the colors array of the gradient layer.

```
gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

gradientLayer.frame = someCGRect

gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.grayColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]

self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```